# Ubuntu 17.10 VPN

Tags: openvpn, ipv6, tcp-ip

Enabling VPN connection from the Network manager automatically add's IPv6 address to DHCP Wired connection even if it's disabled on the settings.
This causes the VPN to leak on all DNS address queries that are for IPv6 addresses.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way that actually works on Debian based distro's.

## Disable IPv6 on Linux

sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1

## Enable

sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0

Answer (score 0):

This detailed blog post might be a big help: https://aaronhorler.com/articles/openvpn-17.10-dns-leak.html

Here is the solution they provided:

> 1. INSTALL UPDATE-SYSTEMD-RESOLVED BY JONATHANIO. [update-systemd-resolved](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved)
>      is a helper script that directly updates the system's DNS settings on
>      connection to an OpenVPN server, and resets them on disconnection.
>      Installation instructions are detailed [here](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved#installation), but, for simplicity, I
>      will repeat exactly what I did.
>      
>      Note that I have [forked](https://github.com/aghorler/update-systemd-resolved) this repository and added kill switch
>      functionality using UFW. If you're interested in a kill switch, you
>      can use my fork instead.
>      
>      Clone the respository, and compile.
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt update
>    sudo apt install git make openvpn
>    git clone https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved.git
>    cd update-systemd-resolved
>    sudo make
>    ```
>
>    Ensure that systemd-resolved is enabled and running.
>
>    ```
>    sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
>    sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved.service
>    ```
>
>    Now, update /etc/nsswitch.conf.
>
>    ```
>    sudo nano /etc/nsswitch.conf
>    ```
>
>    Find the line starting with hosts: , and alter it as below.
>
>    ```
>    hosts: files resolve dns myhostname
>    ```
> 2. ALTER YOUR OPENVPN CONFIGURATION FILE/S. An OpenVPN configuration file usually uses the .ovpn file extension, and is used to connect to
>      a specific server.
>      
>      Locate it, and open it in a text editor.
>
>    ```
>    nano example.ovpn
>    ```
>
>    Add the following lines.
>
>    ```
>    dhcp-option DNSSEC allow-downgrade
>    dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
>
>    script-security 2
>    setenv PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
>    up /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
>    down /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
>    down-pre dhcp-option
>    ```
>
>    `DNSSEC allow-downgrade` will enable [DNSSEC](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/dnssec-qaa-2014-01-29-en) if the server supports it.
>      If you know your server supports DNSSEC (and you don't want to allow
>      downgrades), you can change `allow-downgrade` to `yes`.
>      
>      `dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .` will route all DNS requests through the
>      OpenVPN-specified DNS server.
>      
>      All other lines are required for running the script.
> 3. CONNECT USING THE TERMINAL. Do not connect to OpenVPN using the Network Manager (network-manager-openvpn-gnome). This will guarantee
>      DNS leaks.
>      
>      Instead run OpenVPN from the command line.
>
>    ```
>    sudo openvpn --config example.ovpn
>    ```
>
>    If you're concerned about not being notified of disconnects, I advise
>      you use my [fork of update-systemd-resolved](https://github.com/aghorler/update-systemd-resolved) that implements a simple
>      UFW killswitch.
>      
>      You should no longer be experiencing DNS leaks! [Test here](https://dnsleaktest.com/).